# Why is my connection object null?

Tags: servlets, jdbc, nullpointerexception, dao

```
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ShopDB";
private static final String DB_CLOSE = DB_URL + ";shutdown=true";
private static final String DB_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
private static Connection con = null;

public WebshopDAO() {
    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CLOSE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I created a WebshopDAO object in another class. After that, I called a method in the WebDAO:

```
public CatalogDTO createCatalogDTO() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Catalog";
    CatalogDTO catalog = new CatalogDTO();
    try {
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()) {
                Catalog c = new Catalog();
                c.setCName(rs.getString("CName"));
                c.setCategoryNr(rs.getInt("CategoryNr"));
                c.setSupercategoryNr(rs.getInt("SupercategoryNr"));
                catalog.addCatalog(c);
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return catalog;
}
```

So when I call the createCatalogDTO method, I get a NullPointerException. I don't know why. I checked the driver url and the db url and they are correct. I am using servlets for the first time. The class that uses this WebshopDAO is a servlet and I have a bit of a problem using the debugger.

Can you guys tell me the possible mistakes? I am looking for hours but I just can't find it.

EDIT:

Here is what I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
WebshopDAO.createCatalogDTO(WebshopDAO.java:96)
Navigation.doGet(Navigation.java:28)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: You shoudn't be using a member `Connection` at all, let alone a static one. You should use a new one per request, backed by a connection pool.

Comment: It helps to read the stack trace of exceptions. They tell you what the problem is.